# AWS CLI: The config profile could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Currently working on deploying a yml file to CloudFormation and I have created this profile called awsbootsrap but when my script runs I get an error. My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
STACK_NAME=awsbootstrap
REGION=us-east-2c
CLI_PROFILE=awsbootstrap
EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE=t2.micro

# Deploy the CloudFormation template
echo $CLI_PROFILE
echo -e "\n\n=========== Deploying main.yml ==========="
aws cloudformation deploy --region $REGION --profile $CLI_PROFILE --stack-name $STACK_NAME --template-file main.yml --no-fail-on-empty-changeset --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --parameter-overrides EC2InstanceType=$EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE


# If the deploy succeeded, show the DNS name of the created instance
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    aws cloudformation list-exports --profile awsbootstrap --query "Exports[?Name=='InstanceEndpoint'].Value"
fi
```

where $CLI_PROFILE=awsbootstrap

I get **The config profile (awsbootstrap) could not be found**

Running `aws configure list-profile` shows me my profile -> awsbootstrap

Running `aws configure list` shows

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                <not set>             None    None
```

My `~/.aws/config` looks like this (have also tried with us-east-1 / us-east-2):

```
[profile awsbootstrap]
region = us-east-2c
output = json
```

My `~/.aws/credentials` looks like this:

```
[awsbootstrap]
aws_access_key_id = redacted
aws_secret_access_key = redacted
```

I have no env variables that are creating issues...

Comment: can you remove the output? also what's the result of echo $CLI_PROFILE

Comment: @KerolosWilliam the output is awsbootstrap, I've added the contents of my script to the post

Comment: `[profile awsbootstrap]` replace to `[awsbootstrap]`

Comment: @aviboy2006 Does not work. Pretty sure the profile part is supposed to be there

Comment: okay you can turn on the debug mode in the bash by `set -x ` at the beginning of the script under the shebang line 
and can you update the post with the output ?

Comment: also following this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html
there are something called cli cache  search for this part `Where are configuration settings stored? `